# validating structures - how to pass string to sizeof and offset methods?

Tags: c++

My program contains auto-generated structures. When starting I need to validate them with "server" information - so I can be sure that my auto-generated structures are up to date. Server and local structures are valid if they are of the same size, contain fields with the same name and size (and type ideally should be validated too).

This is what I wrote so far:

```
void SchemeValidator::Validate(cg_scheme_desc_t* schemedesc, Logger& logger)
{
    struct cg_message_desc_t* msgdesc = schemedesc->messages;
    while (msgdesc)
    {
        struct cg_field_desc_t* fielddesc = msgdesc->fields;
        char* structName = msgdesc->name;
        size_t structSize = msgdesc->size;
        logger.Debug("Message %s, block size = %d", structName, structSize);
        if (strcmp(structName, "orders")) {
            if (sizeof(orders) != structSize) {
                printf("Validator error, structure 'orders', local size = %d server size = %d!", sizeof(orders), structSize);
                throw std::exception("Validator error, structure 'orders' wrong size!");
            }
            while (fielddesc)
            {
                logger.Debug("\tField %s = %s [size=%d, offset=%d]", fielddesc->name, fielddesc->type, fielddesc->size, fielddesc->offset);
                if (offsetof(struct orders, fielddesc->name) != fielddesc->offset) {
                    throw std::exception("orders structure offset wrong");
                }
                // TODO: validate fielddesc->size == sizeof corresponding field in structure
                fielddesc = fielddesc->next;
            }
        } else {
            throw std::exception("Validator error, validation not implemented!");
        }

        msgdesc = msgdesc->next;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of problems:

I wrote `if (strcmp(structName, "orders"))` because later i need to use `orders` in several expressions, including `sizeof(orders)` and `offsetof(struct orders, fielddesc->name)`. But I have a lot of structures and for each of them I have to copy-paste this block. Can I somehow pass string literal to `sizeof` and `offsetof` methods or have desired effect some another way?

`offsetof(struct orders, fielddesc->name)` doesn't work by same reason - second parameter can not be string literal, I receive `error C2039: 'fielddesc' : is not a member of 'orders'` error

By the same reason I can validate `fielddesc->size`.

How can I achieve desired validation without intensive copy-pasting and values hard-coding?

Comment: They aren't methods, they are compile-time operators. sizeof operates on a type, and offsetof operates on a type and a member name. You can't pass strings to either of them.

Comment: How about using Google Protocol Buffers or Apache Thrift instead of a homemade messaging protocol?  They have some level of support for things like this built right in.

Comment: I agree with @JohnZwinck. You shouldn't define wire protocols with structs or classes at all, and all this meta checking proves it.

Comment: sorry i do not control server side, it's how stock exchange works

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish what you want by defining structs with typedefs and using a templated function.  The following should replace what you have (obviously not tested)

```
struct OrderType {
   typedef cg_field_desc_t* ListItem;
   typedef orders           Class;
   static const std::string Name;
};

std::string OrderType::Name = "orders";

template <class T>
checkStuff(T::ListItem fielddesc, const char* name, size_t structSize)
{
   if (strcmp(name, T::Name.c_str())) {
      if (sizeof(T::Class) != structSize) {
         printf("Validator error, structure 'orders', local size = %d server size = %d!", sizeof(T::Class), structSize);
         throw std::exception("Validator error, structure 'orders' wrong size!");
      }
      while (fielddesc)
      {
         logger.Debug("\tField %s = %s [size=%d, offset=%d]", fielddesc->name, fielddesc->type, fielddesc->size, fielddesc->offset);
         if (offsetof(T::Class, fielddesc->name) != fielddesc->offset) {
            throw std::exception("orders structure offset wrong");
         }
         // TODO: validate fielddesc->size == sizeof corresponding field in structure
         fielddesc = fielddesc->next;
      }
   } else {
      throw std::exception("Validator error, validation not implemented!");
   }
}
```

You then replace your if statement with

```
checkStuff<OrderType>(fielddesc, name, structSize);
```

You can extend this to other types by defining new structs

```
struct OtherType {
   typedef some_other_t*    ListItem;
   typedef bizbaz           Class;
   static const std::string Name;
};

std::string OtherType::Name = "foobar";
```